Incompatibility between `position_dodge` and `geom_text_repel` on `ggplot2`
I am facing problems on dodging a geom_text_repel label on a graph. I looked other similar questions on the Forum but I was not able to understand exactly how to force the dodging on these labels.
Nuge_x and Nudge_y are not compatible with position_dodge(0.3), but also position_dodge(0.3) on the labels is not working as well.
Is there a method to force it? I tried force =20 unsuccesfully.
Below you can see the code with the test I made and the graph showund the problem.
# Dataframe creation
Dati2 <- data.frame(
  Definition = c("1 min, 40°C", "5 min, 40°C", "1 min, 40°C", "5 min, 40°C", "1 min, 40°C", "5 min, 40°C"),
  Grade = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
  Run = c(35, 35, 46, 46, 46, 46),
  Note = c(NA, NA, "Cade dopo 10''", "Cade dopo 10''", "Cade dopo 8''", "Cade dopo 8''")
)

# Print of Dataframe
print(Dati2)


library(scales)
library(ggrepel)
library(readxl)

library(dplyr) 
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

theme_set(theme_pubclean())



# Graph coding    
Graph2 <- ggplot(Dati2, aes(Definition, Run)) +
  geom_linerange(
    aes(x = Definition, ymin = 0, ymax = Run, group = Grade), 
    color = "lightgray", size = 1.5,
    position = position_dodge(0.3)
    )+
  geom_point(
    aes(color = Grade),
    position = position_dodge(0.3), size = 3
    )+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#0073C2FF", "#EFC000FF", "#4ade40"))+
  coord_flip() +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),  # Inclination of text y
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),                    # Remoxe axis title
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12),            # modify axis title
    legend.title = element_blank(),                     # Remove legend titlelegenda
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(
    aes(label = Note), 
    size = 3, 
#    nudge_x = 0.5,
#    nudge_y = 0.5,
    box.padding = 1,
    point.padding = 0.2,
    max.overlaps = 10,
    na.rm = TRUE,
    min.segment.length = 0,
    position = position_dodge(0.3),
    force =20
  ) 


Graph2



You need to add group = Grade to the mapping for geom_text_repel, and the labels should be dodged properly.
...
  geom_text_repel(
    aes(label = Note, group = Grade),
    ...
  )


You can also use col aesthetic instead of group for the labels to have the same color as the points.

It works, thankyou. I realized that also position = position_dodge(0.3) is fundamental. May I ask you why the definition of the group on the aesthetical works properly on this?

I assume it works similar to color or other aesthetics but without changing visuals. Try to change color to group in geom_point. You will get similar plot but without colored points.
